# How to find the common eigenvectors of these commuting matrices?

Tags: matrix, eigenvalues

Given matrices `P` and `Q` defined as

```
P = {{x - I y, z}, {z, x + I y}}; Q = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
```

It is clear that $[P,QR]=0$ where $R$ is the complex-conjugation operation. My question is how can one find then the simultaneous eigenvectors of $P$ and $QR$?

EDIT-1: Thanks to the responses, I am updating the question with more details.

Why $PQR-QRP=0$ implies $QP-P^*Q=0$? This can be seen by letting $PQR-QRP$ to act on an eigenvector $\vec{x}$ of $P$  with eigenvalue $\lambda$, that is, $P \vec{x} = \lambda \vec{x}$. Noting that $R \vec{x}=\vec{x}^*$ (* is complex-conjugate and not conjugate-transpose), we have
\begin{align}
&(PQR)\vec{x} - (QRP)\vec{x}=0 \vec{x},\nonumber \\
\implies&   (PQ) \vec{x}^* - (QR) \lambda \vec{x}=0,\nonumber \\
\implies& (PQ) \vec{x}^* - Q \lambda^* \vec{x}^*=0, \nonumber \\
\implies& (PQ) \vec{x}^* - Q P^* \vec{x}^*=0 \nonumber \\
\implies& PQ   - Q P^*  =0.
\end{align}

Comment: The trivial approach is to find all the eigenvectors of `P` and then see if they are eigenvectors of `QR`.  Are you interested in matrices that are too large to make this practical?

Comment: @mikado, the Mathematica gives the Eigenvectors of $P$: $v_{\pm} = [(-i y \pm \sqrt{z^2 - y^2})/z, 1]^T$, but these eigenvectors do not seem to be the eigenvectors of $QR$.

Comment: Try `Eigensystem[{P, Q}]`. Probably you should convert the matrices first to real $4 x 4$ metrices...

Comment: I'm not sure you correct in thinking that there are simultaneous eigenvectors (for arbitrary values of `x`, `y`, `z`.  But I may have misunderstood your notation.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you think these matrices commute. The $QR$ is just $Q$, because $Q$ is real, and $P$ and $Q$ definitely don't commute with each other, unless $y=0$.

Comment: @march, note that $[P, QR]=0$ implies $QP=P^*Q$ where $P^*$ is the complex conjugate of $P$.

Comment: I'm confused: complex conjugation does not seem to be a complex-linear transformation. Is $QR.v$ the same operation as `Q. Conjugate[{1 + I, 2 + 2 I}]` for $v=(1+i,2+2i)$?

Comment: Or to put it another way, how do you find the eigenvectors of $QR$? (In Mathematica code.)

Answer (score 3):

From the question and comments, the notation in the question means
$$
[P, QR] = Q P - P^* Q = 0
$$
Indeed,

```
P = {{x - I y, z}, {z, x + I y}};
Q = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}};
FullSimplify[Q.P - ConjugateTranspose[P].Q, Element[{x,y,z}, Reals]]
```

returns

> {{0,0},{0,0}}

Yet,

```
P.Q - Q.P
```

is not zero

> {{0, -2 I y}, {2 I y, 0}}

Because $Q$ and $P$ do not commute they are not simultaneously diagonalizable, that is they do not have common eigenvectors.

However, $P$ and $P^*$ are indeed similar, so there exists a nonsingular $T$ such that
$$
T^{-1} P T = P^*
$$
and
$$
Q P - T^{-1} P T Q = 0
\quad
\implies
\quad R P - P R = 0, \quad R = T Q
$$
It is $R = T Q$ that share common eigenvectors with $P$. Is that what you were looking for?

Edit 1: After your response, what you are looking for cannot be described as a linear complex operator, as pointed out by @Michael E2 in the comments. It can however be described by a linear operator in the reals. In that case, you will be lifting $P$, $Q$, and $R$ into 4x4 real matrices, say $P_r$, $Q_r$, $R_r$, which you can do and will lead to
$$
P_r Q_r R_r - Q_r R_r P_r = 0
$$
as you pointed out. Here $P_r$ and $Q_r R_r$ will be simultaneously
diagonalizable by a matrix containing the four eigenvectors of $P_r$. And those will be just the two complex eigenvectors of the original matrix $P$. There will be two repeats that are linearly independent in the reals but not in the complexes.

Comment: I guess $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is not the standard $[A,B]=AB-BA$ commutator? If it is, why is $[P,QR]=PQR-QRP = QP-P^*Q$? Is there a (conjugate) transpose in there somewhere, and is the fact that $Q$ is symmetric and real being used? (Note the OP said $P^*$ was the conjugate, not the conjugate transpose, of $P$. But your derivation makes it seem likely that conjugate transpose was meant.)

Comment: Things are a bit confusing so that was my take on it. The author said in a comment that * was the complex conjugate and i assumed he meant plus transpose. Either way they will not be simultaneously diagonalizable. My answer was probably better set as a comment but it just didn’t fit.

Comment: @MauriciodeOliveira, I have updated my question. Indeed you verified that $[P, QR]=0$, so all I want are the simultaneous eigenvectors of $P$ and $QR$.